# getting value of listview from a child window to another child window

Tags: c#, wpf

in vb6 i can easily get the value from childwindow to another childwindow.. for example frm1.textbox1.text = frm2.listview.item.selectedindex... how can i do this in wpf?

i have two child window named EmployeProfile and the other one is PrintEmpProfile... in EmployeeProfile window, there is a listview... what i want is if I'm going to click the print button, i can get the value from EmployeeProfile listview....

so far this is what's I've got. this code is inside of PrintEmpProfile

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("EmpIDNumber");
table.Columns.Add("IDNum", typeof(string));
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    table.Rows.Add(new object[] { EmployeeProfile.????? });
}
```

i don't know how to get all values from EmployeeProfile listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you open a child window put a reference of the new child window into a collection. I ssume that MyChild is your child window defined in XAML like:

```
<Window
    x:Class="TEST.MyChild"
    ...
```

You can define a static list holding your child windows in App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static List<MyChild> Children
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == _Children) _Children = new List<MyChild>();
            return _Children;
        }
    }

    private static List<MyChild> _Children;
}
```

Whenever you open child window add it into this collection like:

```
MyChild Child = new MyChild();
App.Children.Add(Child);
Child.Show();
```

You should also remove child from this collection when you close your child window. You can do this in Closed event of the window. Define closed vent in XML:

```
Closed="MyChild_Closed"
```

And in code behind:

```
    private void MyChild_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // You may check existence in the list first in order to make it safer.            
        App.Children.Remove(this); 
    }
```

Whenever a child window wants to access ListView of other child window then it gets reference of the child from the collection and then call ListView defined in XAML directly.

```
    MyChild ChildReference = App.Children.Where(x => x.Title == "Child Title").FirstOrDefault();
    if (null != ChildReference)
{
    ChildReference.listview.SelectedIndex = ...
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply... sorry for being a beginner... how can i create List<MyChild> Windows = new List<MyChild>(); as static in App.xaml? by the way my record in listview was bindable...

Comment: @Kenshi I have extend the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Property Of listview .

```
   public ListView EmployeeListView
    {
        get
        {
            return IdOfYourListView;
        }
        set
        {
            IdOfYourListView = value;
        }
    }
```

Now on PrintEmpProfile Create object of EmployeeProfile

```
      EmployeeProfile empf = new EmployeeProfile();
      ListView MyListView = empf.EmployeeListView;
```